# Как удалённо смотреть логи приложения iOS?

Tags: ios, отладка, iphone

Есть приложение, которое я написал. На моём устройстве оно работает нормально. Но на устройстве другого человека в определённом месте это приложение вылетает.

Обычно, когда я у себя в симуляторе или на устройстве могу воссоздать проблему, то я например вставляю в определённых участках кода print и вывожу туда какие-то данные для теста. Но если устройство подключить напрямую к маку не получается, как тогда быть?

Пробовал Flexihub, не получилось соединиться. Нужные ещё варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если приложение уже в сторе и у другого человека версия оттуда (или из Testflight), а также у человека устройство на iOS 13, то логи падений можно посмотреть напрямую в Xcode (меню Window -> Organizer). Если же у пользователя не iOS 13, можно пользоваться сторонними сервисами для записи крашей (например, Firebase), однако присылаться они начнут только с новой версии приложения.

Если же приложение пока только в разработке, то для подобных случаев может быть полезна запись логов на диск, скажем, в папку Documents. Эти логи затем легко достать, подключившись к iOS-устройству через Finder или iTunes.

Comment: А xcode должен быть 11? Или 10 тоже подойдёт? И если к примеру в коде есть print() они тоже будут в этом логе или там только краши будут?